# How to change view size in IB for iPhone 3.0

Tags: iphone, uiview, resize

I want to change the view size for iPhone 3.0, but I find that in IB, size&Position section, the Width and Height for view was set as fixed values. Does apple forbid us to change its value here. How can I change its Height then?

PS:I use the navigation bar as title bar, so I need to change the height of view to 416 so as to know how much space I can use to organize my controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to see how much room you have with a navigation bar, you can use IB to simulate a navigation bar without actually changing the size of a view. In IB, select the view, then open the Attributes Inspector (Command-1). In there, find the section titled "Simulated User Interface Elements", and change the value for "Top Bar" to "Navigation Bar".